# Does the polygonal pattern on the floor of this "crater" on Mars mean that there's water ice below its surface?

Tags: mars, water, geology, collapse-feature

[This presentation](https://marsoweb.nas.nasa.gov/landingsites/msl/workshops/2nd_workshop/talks/Malin_N_Meridiani.pdf) of the [Program of the Second MSL Landing Site Workshop](https://marsoweb.nas.nasa.gov/landingsites/msl/workshops/2nd_workshop/program.html) shows an image of a "crater" near the equator that is 2.4 km wide and 750 meters deep !

[image: Collapse feature]

On the [Mars Image explorer](https://viewer.mars.asu.edu/viewer/hirise#P=PSP_006570_1820_RED&T=2) you can zoom in on the floor of this possible collapse feature and inspect the [polygonal patterned ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_patterned_ground).

Although on Wikipedia I couldn't find any pattern quite like this, could this mean there's ice in the subsurface of the floor of this "crater"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

This pattern is not directly water/ice-related, it's just dunes - the crater is filled with martian sand and the winds created these ripples.

There are a few other examples of similar patterns - here's a small selection:

https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/the-dunes-in-mars-wirtz-crater
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proctor_(Martian_crater)
https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1206382/NASA-captures-vivid-shot-sand-dune-Martian-crater.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification !  The pattern on the floor of Victoria crater looks much the same.  I saw the pattern inside the shown crater as a collection of bulges !